# BuddyPress group filter

Tags: plugins, buddypress

I want to add filter on my data. I am using BuddyPress there is a default filter on page but I want to add some custom filter. How can I add and get result?

This is the page where I want to use the filter: http://hobbytour.club/groups/

In that there is order by and by name global filter.

There are also two drop downs I want to do filter by that value also.

Answer (score 1):

BuddyPress allows you to add custom filters for members, groups, blogs, and activities.

There's a thorough documentation on [how to add custom filters to loops](https://codex.buddypress.org/plugindev/add-custom-filters-to-loops-and-enjoy-them-within-your-plugin/) and I'd recommend you to check it out. There's a lot of example code that should help you get started.

Comment: i didn't find any custom code to add custom filter.i want to add filter on groups page.can you please help me